# accessing the a form within another linked project, bypassing the entry point

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have three projects  that i have linked via referencing the other two to the main one, is there  a way to access a  form of the within the other project (not the entry point/form) of that project  but any form within.

once user have logged in to the other app/project and linked to the other app, I want to enable them to return to a point within the app/project they linked from bypassing the login page,

right now Im trying this using a class library that is referenced to all the projects, and im trying to access the form with the idea below:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class universalClass
    {

        public void showLanding()

        {
           dummyClientCare.dummyClientCareForm1 LandingForm = new dummyClientCare.dummyClientCareForm1();
            MultiPlierStaffSy.LandingForm LDF = new MultiPlierStaffSy.LandingForm();
            //or some code here to show the LandingForm of the other project
        }

    }
}
```

but in the above class im getting an error

> the type or namespace 'LandingForm' does not exit in the namespace 'MultiPlierStaffSy' (are you missing an assembly reference)

my question is there any way to accomplish the primary goal of bypassing the entry point and go straight to some form deep within the other project when switching between, and also can I accomplish with the class library I just created and referenced.. thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Have you set up dependencies correctly? If so, did you add a reference to the other project in your current project?

Comment: @SaeidYazdani yes all projects in question have each a dependency to the class library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an application project type (creates an .exe file) as a class library. Just add a reference to it from the project. Make sure you don't have a circular reference.

However the correct way to do this would be to move the form you wish to share into a class library and reference that from both projects.

Comment: your second suggestion is very interesting, I will give a try